# Getting Run time 1004 error in code

Tags: vba

I tried the code provided by VBA Express for combining sheet, while executing it is displaying Run Time error 1004: Application Defined or Object Defined Error:

My scenario is: 
I have a Excel, in that I have first sheet "Connection" and after it I have Sheet1, Sheet2 and so on.  I am combining all sheets except sheet "Connection" by saying start with sheet2.

I tried following line of code to exclude "Connection" sheet:
`If Not Sheet.Name = "Connection" then`
but it did not work.

Whatever the sheets I have in some of them I have large data in some cells.

Here is the code which I am using: I have highlighted the line

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
    Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
    Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'Range object
    Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

        If sht.Name = "Master" Then
        sht.Delete

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next sht

     'We don't want screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'trg.SaveAs "C:\temp\CPReport1.xls"

     'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))

     'Rename the new worksheet
    trg.Name = "Master"

     'Get column headers from the first worksheet
     'Column count first

    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(2)

    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column

     'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed

    With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
         'Set font as bold
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

     trg.SaveAs "C:\temp\CPReport1.xls"

     'We can start loop

    'Skip Sheet - Connection
        If Not sht.Name = "Connection" Then
            For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

                'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
                If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
                Exit For
                End If

                'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
                Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
                'Put data into the Master worksheet
'-----------------  Error in below line --------------------------------------------------
                trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
            Next sht

        End If

     'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
    trg.Columns.AutoFit

     'Dim dest, destyfile
     'dest = "E:\Test_Merge\"
     'destyfile = dest & "_" & trg.Name
     'trg.SaveAs (destyfile)
     'Screen updating should be activated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

First issue, if you try to exclude the Connection sheet, you need to do it within the loop, not outside. 
Second, let's try to do paste values rather than your range transfer.

```
        For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
           'Skip Sheet - Connection
            If Not sht.Name = "Connection" and not sht.name="Master" Then

            'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
            Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
            'Put data into the Master worksheet
            rng.copy
            trg.Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues

            End If
        Next sht
```

Full code would now look like this

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

    If sht.Name = "Master" Then
    sht.Delete

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next sht

 'We don't want screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'trg.SaveAs "C:\temp\CPReport1.xls"

 'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))

 'Rename the new worksheet
trg.Name = "Master"

 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first

Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(2)

colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column

 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed

With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
           'Skip Sheet - Connection
            If Not sht.Name = "Connection" and not sht.name="Master" Then

            'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
            Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
            'Put data into the Master worksheet
            rng.copy
            trg.Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues

            End If
        Next sht

'move out the Master sheet
trg.move
activeworkbook.SaveAs "C:\temp\CPReport1.xls"

 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit

 'Dim dest, destyfile
 'dest = "E:\Test_Merge\"
 'destyfile = dest & "_" & trg.Name
 'trg.SaveAs (destyfile)
 'Screen updating should be activated
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I want to save this mastersheet in specified location instead of creating at last of all sheets. And also I dont want to show user other sheets, whatever be the sheets are creating I have to hide them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: I am combining sheets into Master sheet. All these sheets are residing in one excel workbook. I want to hide all those sheets and master aslo. And I have to save Master sheet into different location. Currently I am saving it in new location but when I open it it is showing me all worksheets along with Master sheet.

Comment: I have to display only Mastersheet not others.

Comment: I have updated code to move only the Master sheet to a new workbook and save it. Let me know if that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to save Master sheet named as "Cross Project Req Coverage" with combined values at specified location. Only excel sheet created but not values in it. When we open this mastersheet, at status bar it is showing "Select Destination and PRESS Enter or CHoose paste. Here is my code:

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
    Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
    Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'Range object
    Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

    'We don't want screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
    'Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))

    Dim objcpExcel, objcpSheet
    Set objcpExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objcpExcel.Workbooks.Add

    Set objcpSheet = objcpExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    objcpSheet.Name = "Cross Project Reqs Coverage"

    'Rename the new worksheet
    'trg.Name = "Cross Project Reqs Coverage"

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       'If UCase(Left(ws.Name, 1)) = "S" Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
       'Next ws
    'Get column headers from the first worksheet
    'Column count first

    Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(2)

    colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed

    With objcpSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
        .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
        .Font.Name = "Cambria"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 11
    End With

    'We can start loop

        For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
           'Skip Sheet - Connection
            If Not sht.Name = "Connection" And Not sht.Name = "Cross Project Reqs  Coverage" Then

            'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
            Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
            'Put data into the Master worksheet
            rng.Copy
            objcpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
        Next sht

    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & CPDomain & "_" & CPProject & "_Requirement Coverage.xls"
    'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
    'objcpSheet.Columns.AutoFit

    'Screen updating should be activated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Dim fso
Dim Project_fileCP As String

Dim ReportsFolderDestination
ReportsFolderDestination = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\"
Project_fileCP = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls"

'Project_file1 = "C:\temp\" & project & "_Defects List.xls"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(Project_fileCP) Then
    fso.DeleteFile Project_fileCP, True
    objcpExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (Project_fileCP)
    objcpExcel.Quit
    MsgBox " Cross Project Requirement Coverage Report Generated..Please check in QC Downloader Reports folder on Desktop!!!", vbInformation, "Cross Project Requirement Coverage Generated.. "
    Application.StatusBar = False

If Dir("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls") <> "" Then
    Kill "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls"
    OldFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' original file location
    NewFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' new file location"
    Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file
Else
    OldFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' original file location
    NewFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' new file location"
    Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file
End If
'Workbook_Deactivate
Else
    objcpExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (Project_fileCP)
    objcpExcel.Quit
    'MsgBox " Defect List Created..Check on Desktop!!!", vbInformation, "Defect List Created.. "
    MsgBox " Cross Project Requirement Coverage Report Generated..Please check in QC Downloader Reports folder on Desktop!!!", vbInformation, "Cross Project Requirement Coverage Report Generated.. "

    Application.StatusBar = False

If Dir("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls") <> "" Then
    Kill "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls"
    OldFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' original file location
    NewFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' new file location"
    Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file
Else
    OldFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' original file location
    NewFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\QC Downloader Reports\" & "Cross Project Reqs Coverage.xls" ' new file location"
    Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file
End If

End If

' If error occurs It will take care of that
ErrorHandling:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Error Occurred.."
        MsgBox "Please check entered Path!!!", vbInformation, "Incorrect Value"
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to save Master sheet named as "Cross Project Req Coverage" with combined values at specified location. Only excel sheet created but not values in it. When we open this mastersheet, at status bar it is showing "Select Destination and PRESS Enter or CHoose paste. Above is my code